# Can't read unit test success rate, can read unit test coverage generated by jacoco

Tags: java, ant, testng, sonarqube, jacoco

I hope to use sonar,jacoco,testng,ant to show Unit Test success rate and Unit Test coverage. And I can generate coverage report by jacoco and show it in Sonar. But Sonar can't show the Unit Test success rate. The "Unit Test Success" is always equals to 0 as shown below.
[image]

In fact, testng could generate test report (Include the number of total test case, failed test case and succeed test case).

How can sonar read these reports and show us in sonar dashboard?

And my build.xml is shown below:

```
<!-- ========= Define the main properties of this project ========= -->
<property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src" />
<property name="test.dir" value="${basedir}/test" />
<property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib" />
<property name="build.dir" value="${basedir}/build" />
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes" />
<property name="dist.dir" value="${build.dir}/dist" />
<property name="resource" value="${basedir}/resource" />
<property name="jar-file" value="${dist.dir}/Calculate-1.0.jar" />
<property name="reports.dir" value="${build.dir}/reports" />
<property name="reports.jacoco.dir" value="${build.dir}/reports/jacoco" />

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
        <include name="lib/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
        <include name="dist/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path> 

<!-- ========= Define "regular" targets: clean, compile, ... ========= -->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${reports.jacoco.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" fork="true" debug="true" includeAntRuntime="true" />
    <javac srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" fork="true" debug="true" includeAntRuntime="true" />
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${jar-file}" basedir="${classes.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="test" depends="jar">
    <taskdef name="testng" classname="com.beust.testng.TestNGAntTask">
            <classpath path="${lib.dir}/testng-6.8.5.jar"/>
    </taskdef> 
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="resource/antlib.xml"> 
        <classpath path="${lib.dir}/jacoco-ant-task-core-agent.jar" />
    </taskdef>
    <jacoco:coverage destfile="${reports.jacoco.dir}/jacoco.exec" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
        <testng classpath="${lib.dir}/testng-6.8.5.jar" classpathref="classpath" outputDir="${reports.dir}" haltOnFailure="false" >
            <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml" />
            <sysproperty key="testdata" value="${test.dir}" />
            <jvmarg value="-Dtest.resources.dir=${test.dir}" />
        </testng>
    </jacoco:coverage>
</target>
```

-->

```
<!-- ========= Define Sonar target ========= -->
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="org.codehaus.sonar:example-java-ant" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="Simple Java Project analyzed with the Sonar Ant Task" />
<property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />
<property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
<property name="sonar.sources" value="${src.dir}" />
<property name="sonar.tests" value="${test.dir}" />
<property name="sonar.binaries" value="${classes.dir}" />
<property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="reuseReports" />
<property name="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
<property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="${reports.jacoco.dir}/jacoco.exec" />
<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://localhost:9000" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar" />
<!--<property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="${reports.dir}" />-->
<!--
  <property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="..." />
  <property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="..." />
-->
<target name="sonar" depends="compile">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonar-ant-task-*.jar" file in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
        <classpath path="${lib.dir}/sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar" />
    </taskdef>      
    <!-- Execute Sonar -->
    <sonar:sonar />
</target>
<target name="all" depends="clean,init,compile,jar,test,sonar" />
```

Comment: You have the property controlling reading your existing reports commented out.  What happened when you uncommented it?

    <!--<property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="${reports.dir}" />-->

Comment: As far as I know, this property is just for junit report ,not for tesng report. When I uncomment it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah.  Per [this site](https://wiki.cantara.no/display/dev/Code+coverage+using+Surefire,+TestNG,+Jacoco+and+Sonar), Sonar doesn't support TestNG, but you can have testNG generate the reports in JUnit format.

Comment: Hi Jeanne. I use ReportNG to generate Junit format XML report now. But the "Unit Test Success" still be 0. I modify "testng" taskdef as below.     <testng classpath="${lib.dir}/testng-6.8.5.jar" classpathref="classpath" outputDir="${reports.dir}" haltOnFailure="false" useDefaultListeners="false" listeners="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter">
    <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml" />
    <sysproperty key="org.uncommons.reportng.title" value="Test Report" />
    <jvmarg value="-Dtest.resources.dir=${test.dir}" />
   </testng>

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for Jeanne's answer. I solved it now. As Jeanne said, sonar doesn't support TestNG, it supports JUnit. So I use ReportNG to generated test report in xml format. The report file will be named as com.abc.classTest1.xml. In order to show the Unit Test Success in sonar successfully, we should change it's name to TEST-com.abc.classTest1.xml. Below is my final version of build.xml.

```
<!-- ========= Define the main properties of this project ========= -->
<property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src" />
<property name="test.dir" value="${basedir}/test" />
<property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib" />
<property name="build.dir" value="${basedir}/build" />
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes" />
<property name="dist.dir" value="${build.dir}/dist" />
<property name="resource" value="${basedir}/resource" />
<property name="jar-file" value="${dist.dir}/Calculate-1.0.jar" />
<property name="reports.dir" value="${build.dir}/reports" />
<property name="reports.jacoco.dir" value="${build.dir}/reports/jacoco" />
<property name="junitreport.dir" value="junitreport" />

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
        <include name="lib/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
        <include name="dist/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path> 

<!-- ========= Define "regular" targets: clean, compile, ... ========= -->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir=".sonar" />
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${junitreport.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${reports.jacoco.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${junitreport.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" fork="true" debug="true" includeAntRuntime="true" />
    <javac srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" fork="true" debug="true" includeAntRuntime="true" />
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${jar-file}" basedir="${classes.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="test" depends="jar">
<!--    <taskdef name="junit" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>  -->
    <taskdef name="testng" classname="com.beust.testng.TestNGAntTask">
            <classpath path="${lib.dir}/testng-6.8.5.jar"/>
    </taskdef> 
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="resource/antlib.xml"> 
        <classpath path="${lib.dir}/jacoco-ant-task-core-agent.jar" />
    </taskdef>
    <jacoco:coverage destfile="${reports.jacoco.dir}/jacoco.exec" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
        <testng classpath="${lib.dir}/testng-6.8.5.jar" classpathref="classpath" outputDir="${reports.dir}" 
        haltOnFailure="false" useDefaultListeners="false" listeners="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter">
            <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml" />
            <sysproperty key="testdata" value="${test.dir}" />
            <sysproperty key="org.uncommons.reportng.title" value="My Sonar Test Report" />
        </testng>
<!--        <junit fork="yes" dir="" failureProperty="test.failed">
            <classpath location="${classes.dir}" />
            <classpath refid="classpath" />

            <formatter type="xml" />
            <batchtest todir="${junitreport.dir}">
                <fileset dir="${test.dir}">
                    <include name="com/cisco/sonar/CalculateTestJunit.java" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>    -->
    </jacoco:coverage>
</target>   

<!-- ========= Define Sonar target ========= -->
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="org.codehaus.sonar:example-java-ant" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="Simple Java Project analyzed with the Sonar Ant Task" />
<property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />
<property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
<property name="sonar.sources" value="${src.dir}" />
<property name="sonar.tests" value="${test.dir}" />
<property name="sonar.binaries" value="${classes.dir}" />
<property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="reuseReports" />
<property name="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
<property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="${reports.jacoco.dir}/jacoco.exec" />
<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://1.2.3.4:9000" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://1.2.3.4:9092/sonar" />
<property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="${reports.dir}/xml" />
<!--
  <property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="..." />
  <property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="..." />
-->
<target name="sonar">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonar-ant-task-*.jar" file in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
        <classpath path="${lib.dir}/sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar" />
    </taskdef>      
    <!-- Execute Sonar -->
    <sonar:sonar />
</target>
<target name="all" depends="clean,init,compile,jar,test,sonar" />
```